# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ShoppingCart' of undefined at Object.eval

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7, ionic4

*.html*

```
  <div *ngFor="let p of (products$ | async)?.result.categories.ShoppingCart;">
        {{p.price}}
   </div>
```

*.ts*

```
this.products$ = this.bikeShopService.get();
```

postman

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "categories": [
                {
                    "ShoppingCart": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Golf Clubs",
                            "price": "125",

}]}]}
```

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ShoppingCart' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (BikeShopListPage.html:22)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:23813)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23209)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:23450)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23392)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23215)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:23450)
>       at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:23413)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23210)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:23450)

**Q:** Can you tell me how to access the above data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `.result[0]?.categories[0]?.ShoppingCart`

**result** and **categories** are arrays and not objects

Answer (score 0):

Your items are Arrays, you might want to consider taking out the array part [] or if arrays/lists are needed give the Objects in your array UID's

ngFor can be used in HTML or .map() in a function